# How do I "valueOf" an enum given a class name?

Tags: java, enums

Lets say I have a simple Enum called Animal defined as:

```
public enum Animal {
    CAT, DOG
}
```

and I have a method like:

```
private static Object valueOf(String value, Class<?> classType) {
    if (classType == String.class) {
        return value;
    }

    if (classType == Integer.class) {
        return Integer.parseInt(value);
    }

    if (classType == Long.class) {
        return Long.parseLong(value);
    }

    if (classType == Boolean.class) {
        return Boolean.parseBoolean(value);
    }

    // Enum resolution here
```

}

What can I put inside this method to return an instance of my enum where the value is of the classType?

I have looked at trying:

```
    if (classType == Enum.class) {
        return Enum.valueOf((Class<Enum>)classType, value);
    }
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `classType` isn't `Enum`, it's `Animal`. So,

```
if (classType.isEnum()) {
    return Enum.valueOf(classType, value);
}
```

should work. Additionally, you ought to use `equals()` rather than `==` for comparing the class instances (although `==` will work in practice, if there's just one classloader around).

Comment: But Class doesn't override equals(), so I guess equals() won't work either if there are multiple class loaders.

Comment: Umm, I guess you're right. Actually I don't know how multiple class loaders work together, nor if it's actually likely (or even possible) that there are multiple instances of the same class object around. Perhaps `Class#isAssignableFrom()` could be used too. That said, using `equals()` is hardly wrong.